# setup.py, setup() plus some other stuff

Tags: python, scripting, setup.py

`setup.py` can contain any sort of Python code besides the call to the function `setup()`, I tested it with the following snippet:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='MyPackage',
      packages=['mypackage'])

print "After setup()"
```

The `print` statement was executed normally. I tested this because the command (`python setup.py install`) made me doubt. Should I fearlessly treat `setup.py` as an arbitrary script that handles all my installation needs?

The background goes something like this: I'm writing a Python package that works as a stand-alone program, it's not intended to be imported. In `distutils` I found almost everything I need to handle the installation details like copying a script to the system path, copying extra data files, creating directories, etc. But there's still some procedures that go out of `distutils`' scope, e.g. system calls.

Should I just put this extra code I need into `setup.py`?

Comment: What additional procedures do you need to perform?

Comment: basically some system calls to check if certain applications are installed.

Answer (score 1):

This recent blog post should answer most of your questions:

http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/5-tips-for-packaging-your-python-projects/

A lot of work-in-progress, but not yet available, regarding packaging in Python world.

Comment: tip #2 was really helpful. Since this is not intended to be a Python module I'm considering dropping disutils at all and just writing an installation script to do all the bulk. What are your thoughts about that?

Comment: If you are not going to distribute the package in pypi.python.org please use method what's suitable for you and dismiss setuptools, distutils, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at http://paver.github.com/paver/, which makes extending distutils with some project-specific tasks a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

If an error occures during the execution of setup(), the program will stop and no further code will be executed. But you might still want some additional code to be executed.
In this case, use:

```
from setuptools import setup

try:
    setup(name='MyPackage',
          packages=['mypackage'])

finally:
    print "After setup()"
```